# recvfrom works with INADDR_ANY, but specifying certain interface doesn't work

Tags: c++, sockets, networking, redhat, rhel7

I wrote a program that join source specific multicast group and receive udp multicast packets:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <net/if.h>

typedef unsigned int        UINT32;

int join_ssm_group(int s, UINT32 group, UINT32 source, UINT32 inter) {
    struct ip_mreq_source imr; 
    imr.imr_multiaddr.s_addr  = group;
    imr.imr_sourceaddr.s_addr = source;
    imr.imr_interface.s_addr  = inter;
    return setsockopt(s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_ADD_SOURCE_MEMBERSHIP, (char *) &imr, sizeof(imr));  
}

UINT32 LISTEN_INTERFACE = inet_addr("10.10.1.2");

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    if (argc<3) {
        printf(" Use: %s <group> <source> <port>", argv[0]);
        return 1;
    }

    //  Make socket 
    int sd = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_DGRAM,IPPROTO_UDP);

    struct sockaddr_in Sender;
    socklen_t SenderAddrSize = sizeof( Sender );

    struct sockaddr_in binda;

    //  Bind it to listen appropriate UDP port
    binda.sin_family = AF_INET;
    binda.sin_port = htons( atoi(argv[3]));
      = INADDR_ANY;
    // binda.sin_addr.s_addr = LISTEN_INTERFACE;
    bind(sd,(struct sockaddr*)&binda, sizeof(binda));

    // Join to group
    join_ssm_group( sd, inet_addr(argv[1]), 
        inet_addr(argv[2]), 
        INADDR_ANY );

    char        buf[65536];
    UINT32      seq;

    while(1) {
        printf("try receive\n");
        int res=recvfrom(sd,(char*)buf,sizeof(buf),0, (struct sockaddr *)& Sender, &SenderAddrSize);
        printf("received\n");
        seq = *(UINT32*)buf;
        printf("scr=:%12s;\tseq=%6d;\tlen=%4d\n", inet_ntoa(Sender.sin_addr), seq, res);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

It works fine but note that I'm using `binda.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;`. netstat shows this:

```
netstat -a | grep 16002
udp        0      0 0.0.0.0:16002           0.0.0.0:*
```

When I change it to `binda.sin_addr.s_addr = LISTEN_INTERFACE;` program stops working - it can not recieve packets, it hangs in `recvfrom`. netstat shows this:

```
netstat -a | grep 16002
udp        0      0 localhost.localdo:16002 0.0.0.0:*
```

In both cases tcpdump shows that data is online, so the problem is that I can not receive data on the specific interface, only on ALL interfaces. I'm using RHEL 7, teaming, and LISTEN_INTERFACE is the IP of the corresponding VLAN. Why my code doesn't work and how to troubleshoot it? I do not want to use INADDR_ANY for performance reasons - listening ALL interfaces would be more expensive than listeining certain interface.

**upd** passing LISTEN_INTERFACE to both `join_ssm_group` and and `binda.sin_addr.s_addr` doesn't work too. BTW similar Windows version of such code works on the same PC under Windows Server 2008 R2, but it doesn't work in RHEL 7. I guess I should check these:

- if RHEL 7 receives data on the requreid interface on the required port (answer is Yes, proved by tcpdump)
- if socket is listening on the required interface on the required port (answer is Yes, proved by netstat?)
- if both answers above are Yes then how is it possible that call to `recvfrom` doesn't receive data?

Well probably this question more about RHEL 7 now, than about c++.

Comment: i've executed `systemctl stop firewalld` also i followed this fix https://access.redhat.com/solutions/53031 also I'm using `binda.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;` and now i'm abble to receive packets. I'm stil trying to understand how to specify certain network interface to listen because listening on all interfaces probably would be too slow/expensive/not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

When you join the multicast group you need to specify the same interface that you are listening on, or join it via all interfaces in a loop.

However listening on all interfaces is the norm. It is not 'slow', and it is a 'good idea', unless you have a specific reason to restrict who can connect.

Comment: I've tried to use `LISTEN_INTERFACE` instead of INADDR_ANY in both places (join_ssm_group and binda.sin_addr.s_addr) - this doesn't help. In ultra low latency applications it's important not to add unnecessary overhead so I strongly prefer to listen exact interface instead of listening ALL (there are many VLANs and several physical NIC's on the server)

Comment: There is no 'overhead'.

Comment: in my opinion when you listening to socket you spent some resources - can you prove somehow that there are no `overhead`, add prooflink or something?

Comment: G.R. Wright & W.R. Stevens, *TCP/IP Illustrated,* Volume II: The Implementation, Addision Wesley 1995, *passim.*

Comment: Thanks, i don't have this book unfortunately, so can't read this right now. How listening on all interfaces works? isn't it security problem? can I receive odd packets from wrong interface? anyway i don't see any reasons to listen for all interfaces, when i need the data only from certain interface.

Comment: There is no reason to listen on all interfaces if you only need the data from one of them. However there is also no need to avoid it based on spurious performance concerns which result entirely from your own opinions rather than factual knowledge. And if you listen to all interfaces, *of course* you will receive from all interfaces. If that's a security issue for you, don't do it. But don't fabricate spurious reasons for your choice.

Comment: thanks, well I still want to listen just one interface and still don't know how to do that